# timestamp VS TIMESTAMP_NTZ in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, iso, snowflake-schema, dbt

I am using an sql script to parse a json into a snowflake table using dbt.

One of the cols contain this datetime value: '2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000'.

What's the correct way to define ISO datetime's data type in Snowflake?

I tried `date`, `timestamp` and `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` like this in my dbt sql script:

```
JSON_DATA:",my_date"::TIMESTAMP_NTZ AS MY_DATE
```

but clearly, these aren't the correct one because later on when I test it in snowflake with select * , I get this error:

```
SQL Error [100040] [22007]: Date '2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000' is not recognized
```

or

```
SQL Error [100035] [22007]: Timestamp '2022-02-13T03:32:55+0100' is not recognized
```

so I need to know which Snowflake time/date data type suits the best for this one

EDIT:
This is what I am trying now.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_DATA:"date_transmission" AS DATE_TRANSMISSION
  , TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRANSMISSION:text, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AS DATE_TRANSMISSION_TS_UTC
    , JSON_DATA:"authorizerClientId"::text AS AUTHORIZER_CLIENT_ID
  , JSON_DATA:"apiPath"::text API_PATH
    , MASTERCLIENT_ID
  , META_FILENAME
  , META_LOAD_TS_UTC
  , META_FILE_TS_UTC
FROM {{ source('INGEST_DATA', 'TABLENAME') }}
```

I get this error:

```
000939 (22023): SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 4
10:21:46    too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(GET(DATE_TRANSMISSION, 'text'), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')] expected 1, g
```

However, if I comment out the the first 2 lines(related to timpstamp types), the other two work perfectly fine. What's the correct syntax of parsing json with TO_TIMESTAMP?

Not that `JSON_DATA:"apiPath"::text API_PATH` gives the correct value for it in my snowflake tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some testing and it seems you have 2 options.

You can either get rid of the +0000 at the end: `left(column_date, len(column_date)-5)`

or try_to_timestamp with format
`try_to_timestamp('2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS+TZHTZM')`

TZH and TZM  are TimeZone Offset Hours and Minutes

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 main points here.

1. when getting data from JSON to pass to any of the timestamp functions that want a `::TEXT` object, but the values to get from JSON are still `::VARIANT` so they need to be cast. This is the cause of the error you quote

   > (22023): SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 4
   > 10:21:46    too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(GET(DATE_TRANSMISSION, 'text'), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')] expected 1, g

   also your SQL is wrong there it should have been

   ```
       TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRANSMISSION::text,
   ```
2. How you handle the timezone format.As other have noted you (as I did in your last question) do you want to ignore the timezone values or read them. I forgot about the `TZHTZM` formatting. Given you have timezone data, you should use the `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ``TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`to make sure the time zone data is keep, given you second example shows`+0100`

putting those together (assuming you didn't want an extra `date_transmission` as a variant in you data) :

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(JSON_DATA:"date_transmission"::text, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS+TZHTZM') AS DATE_TRANSMISSION_TS_UTC
    , JSON_DATA:"authorizerClientId"::text AS AUTHORIZER_CLIENT_ID
    , JSON_DATA:"apiPath"::text AS API_PATH
    , MASTERCLIENT_ID
    , META_FILENAME
    , META_LOAD_TS_UTC
    , META_FILE_TS_UTC
FROM {{ source('INGEST_DATA', 'TABLENAME') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `timestamp` (not `date` which does not store the time information), but probably the format you are using is not autodetected. You can specify the input format as `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM` as shown [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html). The autodetected one has a `:` between the `TZHTZM`.

Comment: Could you help with the syntax? I tried this ```TO_TIMESTAMP(JSON_DATA:"date_transmission", 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AS DATE_TRANSMISSION_TS_UTC``` but it throws syntax errors

Comment: you should post all your code, as it seems fine (but the format is not the one of the example you posted)

Comment: can you see the updated qs?

Comment: what if you use TO_TIMESTAMP(JSON_DATA:"date_transmission"::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') ? (without using the new variable name, using two :: and the right format)